# Increase height of custom TextView in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to increase height of my custom `TextView` so I can draw some lines below `TextView`. Can anyone help me how can I do that? Here is my custom `textview`.

**CustomTextView**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView{

   public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);init();
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs); init();
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);init();
        }

        private Paint mStrokeBrush;
        private void init(){
            mStrokeBrush= new Paint();
            mStrokeBrush.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        }   
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(0f, getHeight());
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), 0, mStrokeBrush);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I removed a bunch of code which wasn't relevant to your question. Sorry if it caused confusion.

---

This is a modification of my own code, which adds 20dp to the view's height.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Set view dimensions. Add 20dp.
    //
    int dp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setMeasuredDimension(viewWidth, viewHeight + dp);
}
```

Comment: or `TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`. Also you need to cast it into `int`. `setMeasuredDimension()` doesn't take `float`.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh good catch. Funny how reliant you become on intellisense to catch these sorts of things.

Comment: Ok my problem is that I cannot get viewHeight.. How do I calculate that..I mean how do I measure Height of text in a textView?

Comment: onMeasure is called by Android with the measureSpec parameters. Calling getSize on the heightMeasureSpec will return the height of your custom TextView. You then set the height to be 20 dp greater.

Comment: @bipin Sorry, I noticed that I did not consistently name the variables in my example. I fixed the example code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MikeOrtiz. But it is not working. MeasureSpec is sending height of its parent.  Here is debugging window [link] http://postimg.org/image/b11koi5yr/. Again I want height of textView + some values

Comment: onMeasure's parameters are the size of the View, not the parent. I'm guessing from the link provided that you set the width and height of your CustomTextView to `match_parent`. If that's the case, then I don't see how increasing the height of the View will help. Anyway, take a look at the method `getLineHeight()`, which will return the height of one standard line of text in pixels.

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider implementing a custom view that does not extend TextView, but rather has a TextView inside of it. Then, you can simply call getHeight() on the TextView inside your custom view.